# google index - will google index my logs?

Tags: google-index

I have some txt log files where i print out some important activities for my site.
These files ARE NOT referenced from any link within my site, so it's only me i know the url
(they contain current date in the filname so i have one for each day).

Question: will google index these kind of files?
I think google indexes only the pages whom urls are on the site.

Can you confirm my assumption? I just do not want others to find the link from google etc:)

Comment: It shouldn't but you shouldn't assume it shouldn't. Use some kind of authentication/authorization to prevent access to the files.

Answer (score 2):

In theory they shouldn't. If they aren't linked from anywhere they shouldn't be able to find them. However I'm not sure if stuff can make its way into the index by virtue of having the google toolbar installed. Definitely I've had some unexpected stuff turn up in search engines. The only safe way would be to password protect the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Google can not index pages that it doesn't know they exist, so it won't index these, unless someone posts the url's to google, or place them on some website.

If you want to be sure, just disallow indexing for the files (in /robots.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use the **robots.txt** to prevent the google crawler from indexing files you don't want to show up.

This description from Google Webmaster Tools is very helpful and leads you through the process of creating such a file:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608

edit: As it was pointed out in the comments there is no guarantee that the robots.txt is used so password-protecting the folders is also a good idea.

Comment: Just a note here: `robots.txt` is not honored by all search engines, so this is not reliable if the files include sensitive data.

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to point out that it is better to use the robots.txt compared to using nothing and that I wouldn't rely on google not finding documents that are not linked. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Yea, for regular files that do not contain sensitive data this is a good way of preventing Google from indexing the files :)